# Get a slice of a sorted list according to a key in Python

Tags: python, sorting, slice

Is it possible to slice a sorted list based on some key value (e.g the length of the list items)? If so, how?

For example I get a sorted list like this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(some_list, key=len)
```

Now I want to get a slice containing all items with the lowest and equal len (i.e. all items of len: `min(sorted_list, key=len)` ) which should be the at the head of the sorted list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group the items first, then take the elements of the first resulting subiterator.

```
from itertools import groupby


firsts = list(next(groupby(sorted(some_list, key=len), len))[1])
```

For example,

```
>>> some_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1], [2], [2, 3]]
>>> list(next(groupby(sorted(some_list, key=len), len))[1])
[[1], [2]]
```

Comment: Nice answer although is the `_,` a mistake? or am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming I wrote this correctly, each element yielded by `groupby` is a tuple consisting the "value" of the group and the elements of the list sharing that value. The OP doesn't necessarily care about the length of the shortest lists, only the lists themselves, so `_` is the conventional "don't-care" variable name. We don't use it, so we don't bother coming up with a better name for it.

Comment: gives me the error `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`

Comment: Ah, right, because `next` yields a single tuple; I don't want to iterate over that, just grab the second element.

Comment: Fixed: call `next`, then index that to get the subiterator that will yield the shortest lists. That gets passed to `list` to actually retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, it's a really nice solution

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
min_len = len(min(some_list, key=len))
sorted_list = sorted((x for x in some_list if len(x) == min_len), key=len)
```

What this does is it finds the length of the minimum element in the list, and then filters out the elements that are longer than that when the list is passed into the `sorted` function. It requires an extra pass over the data to find the min length, but sorting takes much longer than that, so that time-cost is practically irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

This function sorts the list, gets the key (i.e. the shortest length element), then builds an array containing only elements of equal length.

```
def slice_list(lst, func=len):
    # start by sorting the list
    sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=func)

    # get the key
    key = func(sorted_lst[0])

    # get the slice
    slice = [v for v in sorted_lst if func(v) <= key]
    return slice
```

Since there are no test cases, here is one (if I am interpreting this question correctly)

```
test = ['abcd', 'abcde', 'efgh', '1234', 'abcdef']
print(slice_list(test, len))
```

Outputs

```
['abcd', 'efgh', '1234']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more for curiosity than practicality (since itertools is *really* performant)…you can group by a minimum and avoid the sort in a single pass in the same way you can find the minimum of a list without sorting. Here you just keep track of the current minimum and all the values of the same size. If you find a smaller value scrap the old ones and start again:

```
some_list = ['999', '11', '22', '343', '12', '545', '99', '11', '100', '11']


def minGroup(l, f):
    it = iter(l)
    
    current = [next(it)]
    curr_min = f(current[0])

    for item in it:
        if f(item) < curr_min:
            curr_min, current = f(item), [item]
        elif f(item) == curr_min:
            current.append(item)

    return current
    

minGroup(some_list, len)
# ['11', '22', '12', '99', '11', '11']

minGroup(some_list, int)
# ['11', '11', '11']
```